# Javascript can get row index and get cell data at same time?

Tags: javascript, html

My table can get row index by .rowIndex. Is it possible if I want third column data of row.

My Table :

```
<table width="90%" border="1" id="TestAlert">
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Attribute</td> <td>Thai</td> <td>English</td></tr>
    <tr onclick="myFunction((this))"><td>น้ำหนัก</td><td>...</td><td>WT</td></tr>
    <tr onclick="myFunction((this))"><td>ชื่อรุ่น</td><td>...</td><td>MDL</td></tr>        
    <tr onclick="myFunction((this))"><td>สูง</td><td>...</td><td>HIGH</td></tr></tbody>
    </table>
```

and my script:

```
function myFunction(x) {
if(x.rowIndex != 0){
console.log("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex + "Data 3rd cell: " + **CellData**); //get index
}
```

What function should I use get 'WT' or 'MDL' or 'HIGH' when i click each row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need of adding `onclick` event handler to every `tr`.Rather in js attach `onclick` to `tbody`.

On `click` get the event object & from there get the target. The target will be `td`.`innerHTML` will give the content of the td & `parentNode` will return the `tr` of the `td` from where the event generated.

Use `rowIndex` to get the index of the row. `rowIndex` starts from 0

```js
var table = document.getElementById('TestAlert')
var getTBody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
getTBody.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.parentNode.rowIndex)
  console.log(e.target.innerHTML)
};
```

```html
<table width="90%" border="1" id="TestAlert">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Attribute</td>
      <td>Thai</td>
      <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>น้ำหนัก</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>WT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ชื่อรุ่น</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>MDL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>สูง</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>HIGH</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This only works if the cells don't contain any elements.

Comment: There is no mention of 'element' inside cell in this question

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAllItems(){
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
  const itemsArr = Array.from(items);
  itemsArr.forEach(c=> console.log(c.textContent));
}

getAllItems();
```

Now on your tr element do the following:

```
<tr onclick="getAllItems()"><td>สูง</td><td>...</td><td>HIGH</td></tr>
</tbody>
```